# OCaml: Converting / casting bool to int

Tags: casting, ocaml

How do you cast an ocaml boolean to an integer? (There's no `int_of_bool` function.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one possible implementation:

```
let int_of_bool b = if b then 1 else 0
```

The library OCaml Batteries Included has a function `to_int` in its [BatBool module](http://ocaml-batteries-team.github.io/batteries-included/hdoc2/BatBool.html).

Comment: Is there any reason why OCaml doesn't have a specific function to convert booleans to integers?

Comment: After thinking about this I decided it just isn't something you need to do very often. The OCaml standard library has always been fairly Spartan—in my opinion it's *too* Spartan. Other libraries like Core and Batteries are filling in the gaps with richer, consistent sets of functions, even when they're trivial and/or not commonly used.

Comment: @hlin117: Conceptually there is no reason why boolean and integer are convertible. Why is true 1? Why is false 0? Why not some other number? I can think of no reason except that that those integers are the result of the comparison operators in C, which is pretty irrelevant to OCaml.

Comment: This is a fair comment. But OCaml provides logical operations `land` and `lor` on integers, which provides some justification. You can imagine a bool value as being like a 1-bit integer. Any particular choice for the inverse operation (int -> bool) is harder to motivate I think.

Comment: _"the inverse operation (int -> bool) is harder to motivate I think"_ ...I kind of wanted this yesterday for pattern matching the result of `lor` ... it returns `0` or `1` but matching just `0` and `1` is not exhaustive because the type is `int`. So I matched `0` and `_` and added a comment to remind myself why. TBH I feel like maybe `land` and `lor` should return `bool` instead

Answer (score 6):

In 2020, you can use `Bool.to_int`.
From Bool library documentation:

> `val to_int : bool -> int`
> b is 0 if b is false and 1 if b is true.

Source: https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Bool.html